# before submit event in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid-php

I hav got 2 jquery date picker fields in my form.One for start date and another for end date.
i want to check whether start date is less than end date . for that i used beforesubmit event5 of jqgrid but how to check it using javascript and am using php as server side lang...
please answer me as am beginner to jqgrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also check it in PHP file which you define in your **editurl** in the Grid. If it goes wrong just return the error and check for the returning error in the **AfterSubmit** function in Add Options in your jqGrid.